# Change Phone Ringtone permissions

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, phone

I have tried to copy a ringtone to the usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/ folder, but it will not copy. Is it RO? if so is there a way to change permissions for this folder only [there is information to change it for the whole phone]?

Answer (score 0):

The root filesystem is read-only and you have to remount it in read-write mode with this command

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

and copy the ringtone afterwards.

After that you can restart the phone and the root filesystem will be read-only again.

Comment: Tried that,  But now it does not see the ringtone to copy it - it plays the ringtone ?? but will not copy it to the ringtone folder. Also will not allow removal of a file from the ringtone folder [Permission Denied].

Comment: How did you copy the files? Could you write a step by step list of commands of what you did exactly?

Comment: I only use 2 commands: 

sudo mount -o remount, rw /
and
sudo cp Music/Gabriel.ogg usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/

[The file is there, plays and this is the correct spelling.]